# Fill a cell with the first non-empty entry in a set of columns (from left to right)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, coalesce

1. I am trying to fill a cell with the first non-empty entry in a set of columns (from left to right).

   1. Example Sheet is given below.

[image: Original Sheet]

2. Desired Sheet output is given below.

[image: Desired Sheet output]

3. I am applying array formula `=INDEX(B2:D2,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(B2:D2),FALSE))` in column A and formula is seen in cells A2, A3, A4 as `{=INDEX(B2:D2,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(B2:D2),FALSE))}` but  I am getting the following result instead of desired one.

   [image: sheet after formula is applied]
4. can someone help to point out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) to find the first non-blank cell and pass that back into an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a).

[image: Find First non-blank]

The standard formula in A2 is,

```
=INDEX($B2:$Z2, AGGREGATE(15, 6, COLUMN(A:Z)/SIGN(LEN($B2:$Z2)), 1))
```

Fill down as necessary.

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Your *array* formula should work as any of these,

```
=INDEX(B2:D2,MATCH(1, SIGN(LEN(B2:D2)), 0))
=INDEX(B2:D2,MATCH(0, --ISBLANK(B2:D2), 0))
=INDEX(B2:D2,MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(B2:D2), 0))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula.

Comment: I do not have excel 2010. Array formula suggested by you works very well. I have learnt from you correct way of applying array formula. Thanks.

Comment: Woah, the `Aggregate` function looks interesting - thanks for the info!